# Aliased pipeline using head and cut

Tags: bash, alias

I'd like to create an alias to have a quick view of the table format files with comma separator:

```
alias thead='head | cut -d, -f1- | column -s, -t'
```

Later using it like this

```
thead file.csv
```

However, it doesn't work. What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anything more advanced than a simple command, use a shell function instead of an alias:

```
thead () {
    head -- "$1" | cut -d, -f1- | column -s, -t
}
```

This shell function would run `head` on its first argument, and then send the result through the pipeline (although, since the `cut` gets *all* columns due to `-f 1-`, this part can probably be removed; I'm leaving it in here as you had it in your original pipeline).

Or,

```
thead () {
    head -- "$2" | cut -d "$1" -f1- | column -s "$1" -t
}
```

... to be able to use it as

```
thead ',' filename
```

Or even, to allow for an *optional* delimiter (and use comma if none is given),

```
thead () {
    local delim=','

    if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
        delim=$1
        shift
    fi
    
    head -- "$1" | cut -d "$delim" -f1- | column -s "$delim" -t
}
```

The function definition above could be placed wherever you usually define aliases.

---

The issue with having a pipeline in an alias is that when you use the alias with an argument, this argument would be added to the end of the pipeline, not after the first command in the pipeline.

---

The `bash` manual contains the sentence

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

Comment: that's good, do you know btw how can I adjust it to accept a separator as a parameter to thead?

Comment: @MaxLi See updated answer.

Comment: @MaxLi I noticed that the delimiter was also present in the `column` command and that your `cut` command is a no-op. I fixed delimiter for `column` and added a note about the `cut`.

Answer (score 10):

`alias` expansion is just text substitution which is parsed again by the shell, so when you do:

```
thead file.csv
```

That's just replaced with:

```
head | cut -d, -f1- | column -s, -t file.csv
```

and interpreted again.

If you had written:

```
<file.csv thead
```

or

```
cat file.csv | thead
```

or

```
{ thead; } < file.csv
```

It would have worked as it would have been replaced with:

```
<file.csv head | cut -d, -f1- | column -s, -t
cat file.csv | head | cut -d, -f1- | column -s, -t
{ head | cut -d, -f1- | column -s, -t; } < file.csv
```

respectively. In any case, as @Kusalananda says, it's much better to use functions or scripts than aliases for that. Here, I'd just do:

```
thead() { head "$@" | cut -d, -f1- | column -s, -t; }
```

So you can do `thead -n 12 file.csv file2.csv` for instance.

Comment: I think this is the better answer as it clearly explains why the OP’s attempt didn’t work.